# How to config Bearer Token when making a GET request?

Tags: python, api, python-requests

Here is the `Bearer Token` in Postman:

[image]

Here is what I do in code:

```
url_apollo = https://
params_apollo = {
    'ID': 123,
}
```

Here is the `requests` that I made:

```
r_apollo = requests.get(url = url_apollo, 
                        params = params_apollo, 
                        headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + 'Token'})
```

> simplejson.errors.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1
> (char 0)

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

```
url_apollo = https://
params_apollo = {'ID': 123}
headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer YOURTOKENHERE'}

r_apollo = requests.get(url=url_apollo, 
                        params=params_apollo, 
                        headers=headers)
```

The reason why you get that error message is within the "params_apollo" variable. Since "ID" is the last line in the JSON, the comma after the value is incorrect and raises a JSONDecodeError.

Comment: its not the problem, I removed some params to make it simple but forgot the comma

Comment: i did not see any different comparing to my code

Comment: Could you post the stacktrace your getting?